# Parse error creating Erlang JSON string

Tags: json, string, parsing, erlang

I'm having trouble properly escaping a string I'm trying to use to represent JSON in Erlang. I'm not sure why this particular sequence is giving the parser trouble. I have this string in a Basho Bench configuration file.

```
'{
 "stats":"completed",
 "times":[
    {
        "time":"2014-10-29T23:40:46.558Z"
    }
 ]
}'
```

I am getting this error:

```
23:37:18.521 [error] Failed to parse config file server/http.config.erl: {29,erl_scan,{illegal,atom}}
```

It seems like maybe the issue is the numbers in the string but I don't get how I would escape them. Any thoughts?

Comment: What function do you use for parsing?

Comment: I'm not parsing it directly. It looks like erl_scan doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided insufficient info but anyway, `server/http.config.erl` is not JSON. It is erlang term, so this error is from Erlang parser. The whole text you provided is parsed as atom because of `'` which is delimiter for atoms.

Answer (score 0):

The string is not a string. Single quotes denote an atom. It must be wrapped in double quotes to be interpreted as a string.